# Get HTML of URL without XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

thanks for reading. I'm trying to come up with a Javascript function that would convert the HTML source of a page at an external URL into a variable, so that the whole thing would become editable. The complication is, the URL does not end with a "html, htm, aspx" extension, but instead with a string of input form variables (i.e. ?type=AAA&color=BBB...). Hence the XMLHttpRequest method is out of the question.

Is this doable in JS/jQuery at all? I've heard about the same origin policy, but the following tool manages to do just that, although in PHP: http://www.iwebtool.com/code_viewer

Comment: Where did you get the idea that what the url "ends with" has anything to do with whether it can be loaded by XmlHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest works with any valid url, just give it the appropriate url and you can get the response as text.

However, there is the restriction of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). There are different workarounds to this for different situations, but if you want to be able to manipulate the text you receive then there is really only one option. Use the same javascript as you currently have, just add this as the first line of getUrl:

```
url='/path/to/proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Then, on your server (the same one that's serving the page and its javascript), write proxy.php:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
?>
```

This will make every ajax request you make go to your server, which does not have the restriction of loading from only one domain. The server will load the url you asked for, and reply to you with the response it got from the page it loaded. Note that the above script will only give you the content body (what you see when you view-source) - if you need to access HTTP headers you can relay those too, it will just be more complicated.

Comment: Hi. I've tried this one, but to no avail. Following is the code for this method. It only works with local web pages.

Comment: <code>var http; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
http = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
try { http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {
try { http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {
http = false; } }
}

function getUrl(url) {
http.open("GET",url,false);
http.send();
return http.responseText;
}</code>

Comment: In that case, the problem isn't with the url's form, it's with the fact that you're trying to load a url from another domain name. In order to make javascript more secure, browsers don't let scripts load a url unless it's from the same domain. There are different workarounds for different situations, but it sounds like you want to use a server-side proxy. I've edited how to do this into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same origin policy does apply in this case, however you can do it with a combination of server side code (PHP) and jQuery.  Heres a little example.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    echo($buffer);
?>
```

**jQuery / HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourPhpScript.php",
  data: "url=http://stackoverflow.com"
}).done(function( content ) {
  $('#content').html(content);
  //content is your variable containing the source
});
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, stefan, and sorry for the delay in replying. Your method works flawlessly with short url's, but I encounter the same issue when trying to access the HTML of a page whose url ends with input variables. For example, try http://www.remax-oa.com/real-estate-listings/#mode=1&sl=toronto&mnp=6&mxp=110&pt=20&soh=false&dv=false&do=0 and the function outputs "Bad Request (Invalid URL)". If you have an idea, please advise.

Comment: I've never used curl, though I've seen it recommended plenty of times. Do you know if there's any concrete advantage to using curl here, as opposed to simply `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Added security, more options.

Comment: @user1131175 you'll need to URL encode the URL, my guess is the ampersands are messing it up.